# Definite or indefinite article

Tags: grammar

***Situation 1:**

If I want to say/introduce something about my city to a foreign friend, I will start with:

My city has **(the)** stunning parts on the corners of the city. For examples, to the north, there are many mountainous areas.

Is “the” needed here?

I saw the writter use “the”, but I think that I am not refering to specific stunning parts, in addition, I also refer to stunning parts on the first time, so I wouldn’t use “the” here.

***Situation 2:**

If I want to invite a friend to come over to my house, I will start my invitation like this:

My house has **(a)/(the)** good view. Would you like to visit my house? I will treat you a meal.

“A” or “the” is Correct?
My instincts tell me that “a” is correct to use. I am referring to the view for the first time, "a" is more correct. Right?

ButI also think that I am talking to specific view that is my house’s view, not another houses’ views, which is a specific view, so that “the’ here is also possible.

Could you please help me?

Comment: You are right as regards the articles, but there are other problems with your sentences. The north isn't a 'corner' - you could say "My city has stunning scenery in all directions".

Comment: My city has (the) stunning scenery in suburban area areas. This sentence is not correct with "the" . Right?

Comment: Yes, I said that your instincts as regards the articles are correct.

Comment: What if I still want to use the countable word "parts" instead of uncountable word "scenery". (1) My city has stunning parts in suburban areas. (2) My city has THE stunning parts in suburban areas. A friend of mine say that (1) refers to stunning parts in my city in general. (2) with "the" refers to ALL stunning part in my city. Right?

Comment: Neither version is at all idiomatic. A _part_ of a city is the same as an _area_. A native speaker would probably say something like _Parts of my city are stunning, especially in the suburbs_.

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment any more, but I was going to add that, in my sentence, _Parts of the city_ implies _Some parts_.

Comment: How about these sentences, I tell to my foreign friend: (1)Suburban areas in my city is extremely wonderful. (2) THE Suburban areas in my city is extremely wonderful. Both are correct to use. Right?(1) without "the" means "some suburban areas in my city". (2) with "the" means "ALL suburban areas in my city". Right? Which version is more popular to use in daily life?

Comment: In this context, it makes no difference whether you use _the_ or not - but it's _Suburban areas_ **are** .

Comment: If so, when do "the" mean "all?

Comment: _[All] the most interesting parts of the city are in the suburbs._ (In my experience, it's usually the historic centre of a city that is the most interesting, but your experience may differ!)

Comment: How about this sentence with similar structure, is it the same:
(The) Local people in my city are extremely friendly. With"the" we talk about ALL people in my city. Without the, we talk about people in my city in general. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140850/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-le-hanh).